# Accidentally unmount my pendrive

Tags: lubuntu, live-usb, usb-drive, syslinux

I am new to the linux theme, practically I have not been using debian in the beginning but my computer was slow because it is old so I switched to lubuntu, what I liked but now I wanted to go to another more recent version Due to updates, my version is 18 and I wanted to go to 21, well the issue is that I accidentally was in the file manager and I right-clicked and touched unmount or another option for which my pendrive is no longer visible in the manager of files (of course in the terminal it is visible but it does not come out the same as before), I would like to know what I really did

```
MAJ NAME: MINIMUM SIZE RM TYPE RO MOUNTING POINT
sda 8: 0 0 298.1G 0 disk
└─sda1 8: 1 0 298.1G 0 part /
sdb 8:16 1 29.3G 0 disk
sr0 11: 0 1 1024M 0 rom
```

Comment: There seems to be no partition in your pendrive (assuming that it is device `/dev/sdb`). I don't think that Lubuntu's file manager `pcmanfm` removed any partition, so either there was no partition in the beginning, or you used some other tool, for example Disks alias `gnome-disks`. We get more details if you run the terminal command line `lsblk -o name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint,model` and edit your original question to post the result like you did for `lsblk`without options. It helps us see if there is a file system at the head of the drive (like in the old floppy disks).

Comment: Well that was what I did at first, the 29g came out different from how it is now but use the file editor and select the option that says unmount and from there I no longer see the pendrive as an external drive but in the file manager It does not appear but in the terminal I put the lsblk command and what I mentioned above comes out, I wanted to understand what happened and how to reverse it because in reality I wanted to format on a pendrive or erase everything you have to later make a bootable pendrive

Comment: Unmounting or ejecting a USB drive does not damage it, but unplugging it without unmounting/ejecting might damage its mounted file system(s). Please run this command line in a terminal window like you did with lsblk: `lsblk -o name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint,model` and edit your original question to post the result like you did for lsblk without options. It helps us see if there is a file system at the head of the drive (like in the old floppy disks). When we see it I (and/or other people) can help you get further to solve your problem.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. You cannot upgrade from Lubuntu 18.04 to 21.04 because it is not a supported upgrade path. You can only upgrade from LTS to the next LTS or you can upgrade to each successive standard release every 6 months.  The upgrade path for standard releases is closed because the next several standard releases are already EOL.  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS [is not supported](https://lubuntu.me/focal-released/) due to the change from LxDE to LxQt.  You will need a new installation.

Comment: I'll suggest being exact with details; Lubuntu is a desktop release so is *deb* package based; all *deb* package based releases of Ubuntu (*and flavors*) are *year.month* in format, only *snap* based systems use the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 18), and Lubuntu has no *snap* only products (so no products using the *year* format).

Comment: No, that's not the problem, what I wanted to do is a bootable pendrive that has lubuntu 21, and from there I can use it to be able to change the system either on the computer I use or on another, but as I said before I accidentally touched the button and not I know what I really did but now nothing appears in the file manager that comes by default and this appears in the terminal

Comment: If it is true, I do not know those things, I have only been in this for a short time although I manage well in the terminal I am still a novice in all this but the system is wonderful, the problem is that I cannot alter or see the files that the system has pendrive if in the terminal I looked for guides to format it but it showed something but it was with another version I tried it but the commands did not do the same also I hardly understand what I was doing and I do not like that because it only shows but does not explain what each does

Comment: I went through what I tried with an already established or native program in this case the file manager and well, that didn't work out and that's how I got here as there was not much information and who to consult

Comment: It is still not clear what you are asking.  What is the problem exactly?  If you are trying different commands, you must tell us the commands and the output of each command. Narrative descriptions are not very helpful. Instead you should describe exactly the actual instructions you are providing to your device whether it is commands or keyboard and mouse input and also tell us the exact response of your device